# Injecting jQuery using bookmarklet not working on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was trying to use this bookmarklet:

```
javascript:void((function(doc){if(typeof jQuery=='undefined'){var script_jQuery=document.createElement('script');script_jQuery.setAttribute('src','https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js');document.body.appendChild(script_jQuery);console.log('jQuery included ^_^');}else{console.log('jQuery already included ...');}})(document));
```

to inject jQuery into this page:

```
https://cn.bing.com/dict/?mkt=zh-cn&q=test
```

I opened the page, then opened developer console(I'm using Chrome), switched to network tab, then clicked on the bookmarklet, I noticed that Chrome didn't request https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js, instead it requested the following url:

```
https://cn.bing.com/fd/ls/l?IG=EE977A4E38924F57B34A1371C04323C1&Type=Event.ClientInst&DATA=[{%22T%22:%22CI.AntiMalware%22,%22FID%22:%22CI%22,%22Name%22:%22AC%22,%22Text%22:%22S%3Ahttps%3A//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js%22}]
```

Does anyone know why the bookmarklet doesn't work on this page? how is this page redirecting the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That particular site has monkeypatched `appendChild`, as you can see if you run

```
document.body.appendChild.toString()
```

into the console: it gives you

```
function(n){return t(n,"AC")?u.apply(this,arguments):null}
```

in return instead of `[native code]`, which means the native function has been overwritten.

Note that the patched prototype object is `Element.prototype`, but `appendChild` exists natively on `Node.prototype`, which remains unpatched:

```
Node.prototype.appendChild.toString()
// gives function appendChild() { [native code] }
```

You can `.call` the unpatched `appendChild` instead:

```
(function(doc) {
  if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    var script_jQuery = document.createElement('script');
    script_jQuery.setAttribute('src', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js');
    Node.prototype.appendChild.call(
      document.body,
      script_jQuery
    );
    console.log('jQuery included ^_^');
  } else {
    console.log('jQuery already included ...');
  }
})(document)
```

and then it will be appended successfully. (`typeof jQuery` will then evaluate to `function` rather than `undefined`, and you can see that the correct URL is requested from the network tab)

---

If the site had patched it properly and made all references to `Node.prototype.appendChild` inaccessible, the only solution would be to run your own Javascript *before* the page's Javascript ran, which could be done using a userscript manager like [Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net), `@run-at document-start`, and using instant script injection to save a reference to `Node.prototype.appendChild` before it gets overwritten.

Comment: That looks like a pretty complete assessment and solution

Comment: Very strange. This question disappeared from my [SO results](http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/javascript%20or%20jquery%20or%20html)

Comment: When an answer on a question has a positive score or is accepted (or both), it disappears from the unanswered section, right?

Comment: I clicked on every question on the first page there and none of them had any answers with a score greater than 0, so it's probably due to answer score

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390615/question-disappeared-from-my-results

Comment: Hmm, seems you may be right it disappears after a little while - the "What's the difference" in my meta screen shot is also gone now